# Multiple Select many to many Ruby on Rails not creating associative records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Well, I have a many to many association between Contacts and Lawsuits on a table named Actives. In this case, I'm trying to add many contacts to a lawsuit. The problem is: the actives not saving in lawsuits if select is multiple, only if multiple: false.

Here's the models:

```
    #contact.rb
    class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :actives
    has_many :lawsuits, through: :actives

    #lawsuit.rb
    class Lawsuit < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :actives
    has_many :contacts, through: :actives

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :actives, allow_destroy: true

    #active.rb
    class Active < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    belongs_to :lawsuit
    belongs_to :contact
```

And Here's the migration table:

```
    class CreateActives < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def change
      create_table :actives do |t|
       t.belongs_to :contact, index: true
       t.belongs_to :lawsuit, index: true
       t.datetime :appointment_date
       t.timestamps
      end
     end
    end
```

The controller:

```
    #controller/lawsuit.rb
    #create method

    def create
      @lawsuit = Lawsuit.new(lawsuit_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @lawsuit.save
          format.html { redirect_to @lawsuit, notice: 'Lawsuit was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lawsuit }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @lawsuit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    #require params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :lastname, :cpf, :rg, :birthdate, :profession_id, :marital_status_id, :address,
                                    :zipcode, :city, :state, :district, :number, :actives)
```

The view and output params:

```
    #/views/lawsuits/_form.html.erb
    <%= form_for @lawsuit, html: {class: "ui form"} do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.fields_for :actives do |w| %>
      <%= w.select(:contact_id, Contact.all.pluck(:name,:id), {}, {class:"selectize-generic", multiple: true})  %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit %>

    #Params:
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9dpRjs0e2iQXgYzNqObSyzuvEnVdQYVHos922hbu0UptxiVeZfJgxgbfgFGKOUR16119VFLOfheNGogAOwez/w==", 
    "lawsuit"=>{"autos"=>"", "forum_id"=>"1", "lawyer_id"=>"4", "conciliation_date"=>"", "instruction_date"=>"", "fees"=>"",
    "actives_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"contact_id"=>["", "2", "7", "9"]}}}, "commit"=>"Create Lawsuit"}
```

In last saved Lawsuit:

```
    rails c
    x = Lawsuit.last
    => #<Lawsuit id: 17, forum_id: 1, lawyer_id: 4, fees: nil, autos: "", conciliation_date: "", instruction_date: "", created_at: "2019-08-14 15:43:18", updated_at: "2019-08-14 15:43:18">
    x.actives
    => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Active id: 9, contact_id: nil, lawsuit_id: 17, appointment_date: nil, created_at: "2019-08-14 15:43:18", updated_at: "2019-08-14 15:43:18">]>
```

I've been wasting a lot of time on this, I've already try everything, recreate models, tried simple_form gem, change in params, etc. I'm lost.
Anyone can help?

GitHub for the project: 
https://github.com/killerowns/lawsuit-manager-rails

Comment: Have you looked into or are you aware of nested attributes? https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Hey Kori, yes, I'm aware, I've simply forgot to include in this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that `Active` is a icky name for your model. Why not call it `LawsuitContact`? And then do:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: lawsuit_contacts
#
#  id                :integer          not null, primary key
#  lawsuit_id        :integer
#  contact_id        :integer
#  appointment_date  :datetime
#  created_at        :datetime         not null
#  updated_at        :datetime         not null
#
class LawsuitContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lawsuit
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

Then:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lawsuit_contacts
  has_many :lawsuits, through: :lawsuit_contacts
end
```

And:

```
class Lawsuit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lawsuit_contacts
  has_many :contacts, through: :lawsuit_contacts
end
```

Given that your `params` look something like:

```
{
  "lawsuit"=>{
    "autos"=>"", 
    "forum_id"=>"1", 
    "lawyer_id"=>"4", 
    "conciliation_date"=>"", 
    "instruction_date"=>"", 
    "fees"=>"",
    "actives_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{
        "contact_id"=>["", "2", "7", "9"]
      }
    }
  }, 
  "commit"=>"Create Lawsuit"
}
```

...in your controller you could do something like:

```
def create
  @lawsuit = Lawsuit.new(lawsuit_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @lawsuit.save
      @lawsuit.contacts << Contact.where(id: contact_ids)
      format.html { redirect_to @lawsuit, notice: 'Lawsuit was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lawsuit }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @lawsuit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  @lawsuit = Lawsuit.find_by(id: params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @lawsuit.update(lawsuit_params)

      # Assuming the user can remove a contact from a lawsuit, you'll want to 
      # 'unlink' the lawsuit and the contact by destroying all the relevant
      # LawsuitContact join models:
      @lawsuit.lawsuit_contacts.where.not(contact_id: contact_ids).destroy_all

      # Then, you'll want to add any new contacts that the user might have
      # added:
      @lawsuit.contacts << Contact.where(id: contact_ids)

      format.html { redirect_to @lawsuit, notice: 'Lawsuit was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lawsuit }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @lawsuit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

def lawsuit_params
  params.require(:lawsuit).permit(
    :autos, 
    :forum_id,
    :lawyer_id,
    :conciliation_date,
    :instruction_date,
    :fees
  )
end

def contact_ids
  params[:lawsuit][:actives_attributes].try(:[], '0').try(:[], :contact_id)
end
```

Comment: It worked @jvillian, thank you very much. Now for update, I have to use same controller method?

Comment: Ok, I understand now.

Comment: That was a total bonus answer. U owe me a beer, k?

Comment: But let`s say, that I have another many to many interaction, between users and lawsuits called "passives", this method will not work, right?

Comment: Now, THAT's a whole different question. Pose it as such and I'll take a look. You'll need to give some info about what a "passive" is. And, maybe, how a User is different than a Contact as it relates to actives and passives. But, yeah, it probably would need to be modified to work.